# Saving memory while converting state to a base 64 string

Tags: performance, react-native, memory, mobile

I've got the following code:

```
let { MyProp: {
    // Strip these fields out
    a,
    b,
    c,
    ...rest
}, ...slices } = getState();
slices.rest = rest;
let data = JSON.stringify(slices);
let filename = `${slices.config.userName.replace('@', '_')}_${moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-ss')}`;
let dataBase64 = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
```

Which takes the state, does a few transforms on it and then converts it to a base 64 string.

A problem I'm getting is that on some old devices (only Android so far, but my android test devices are much worse than the ios ones) I'm getting an Out of Memory error. So I was wondering if there are ways I can save memory with these few lines. Can I delete variables after I'm done with them and then GC?

Comment: If you could resize your image with lowering quality down before converting it to base64-format .... this could solve the issue ... cause base-64 format road is only meant to be used with small-images like icons, ...

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli It's not an image, I'm stringifying part of the redux state. I need to convert to base64 because it's the only format the API i'm using to upload accepts